# Actix - two conflicting routes

Tags: rust, actix-web

I have two services,

```rust
#[put("/{bucket_name}")]
pub async fn create_bucket(
    bucket_name: web::Path<String>,
    data: web::Data<crate::AppState>,
) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
```

and

```rust
#[put("/{bucket}/{object_name}")]
pub async fn put_object(
    bucket: web::Path<String>,
    object_name: web::Path<String>,
    data: web::Data<crate::AppState>,
    _req: HttpRequest,
    mut payload: web::Payload,
) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
```

However, the second doesn't work, as it is not found. What can I do to handle both `PUT` but for different functions?

Currently it produces the following errors:

```
2023-05-20T13:12:07.324986Z INFO actix_web::middleware::logger: ::1 "PUT /sardor HTTP/1.1" 409 219 "-" "aws-cli/2.11.20 Python/3.11.3 Darwin/22.5.0 source/arm64 prompt/off command/s3.mb" 0.000900 

2023-05-20T13:12:13.496646Z INFO actix_web::middleware::logger: ::1 "PUT /sardo/5.png HTTP/1.1" 404 40 "-" "aws-cli/2.11.20 Python/3.11.3 Darwin/22.5.0 source/arm64 prompt/off command/s3.cp" 0.000621
```

Registering services:

```rust
let server = HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .wrap(middleware::Logger::default())
            .service(apis::put_object::put_object)
            .service(apis::create_bucket::create_bucket)
            .service(apis::list_buckets::list_buckets)
            .default_service(web::route().to(not_found))
            .app_data(web::Data::new(AppState {
                working_folder: config.working_folder.clone(),
            }))
    });
```

Comment: generally speaking it should just work, make sure that during testing there is no trailing  "/" in the `PUT` for `create_bucket`

Comment: @AhmedMasud, unfortunately, it does not work.
```
2023-05-20T13:12:07.324986Z  INFO actix_web::middleware::logger: ::1 "PUT /sardor HTTP/1.1" 409 219 "-" "aws-cli/2.11.20 Python/3.11.3 Darwin/22.5.0 source/arm64 prompt/off command/s3.mb" 0.000900    

2023-05-20T13:12:13.496646Z  INFO actix_web::middleware::logger: ::1 "PUT /sardo/5.png HTTP/1.1" 404 40 "-" "aws-cli/2.11.20 Python/3.11.3 Darwin/22.5.0 source/arm64 prompt/off command/s3.cp" 0.000621 ```

Comment: hmmm 404 on the second one definitely means that it's not quite getting registered as a service, can you post how you are adding the services into the stack?

Comment: Can you please add the error message to the question by [edit]ing it, code doesn't work well in comments and they aren't the right place for important information anyways.

Comment: Thank you both, @AhmedMasud, I have added the registering

Comment: Can you also provide the full signature for put_object and create_bucket please ( i feel this has something to do with serde not being able to deserialize the match correctly because of some type related issue )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a different way, created one handler which handles all `PUT /{}*`, and inside I match them myself.

```rust
#[put("/{tail}*")]
pub async fn handle_put(_: web::Path<String>, req: HttpRequest) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
    let mut path = Path::new(Url::new(req.uri().clone()));
    let mut message = String::new();

    let routes = [
        ("/{bucket}/{object_name}", "bucket and object"),
        ("/{bucket}", "bucket"),
    ];

    for (pattern, description) in &routes {
        if ResourceDef::new(*pattern).capture_match_info(&mut path) {
            match (path.get("bucket"), path.get("object_name")) {
                (Some(bucket), Some(object_name)) if *description == "bucket and object" => {
                    message = format!("bucket: {}, object_name: {}", bucket, object_name);
                }
                (Some(bucket), None) if *description == "bucket" => {
                    message = format!("bucket: {}", bucket);
                }
                _ => return Ok(HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish()),
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    if message.is_empty() {
        Ok(HttpResponse::NotFound().finish())
    } else {
        Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().body(message))
    }
}
```